# Error getting App Check token; using placeholder token instead . Can't pass through user authentication via sms

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, firebase-app-check

[image]I have a flutter application, on the production, as user authorization i use firebase-fcm

```
  await auth!.verifyPhoneNumber(
    phoneNumber: phone,
    verificationCompleted: (PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
      auth!.signInWithCredential(credential);
    },
    verificationFailed: (FirebaseAuthException e) {
      print('Verification failed: ${e.message}');
    },
    codeSent: (String verificationId, int? resendToken) {
      fcmVerificationId = verificationId;
    },
    codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationId) {
      
    },
  );
```

App check configured as it was in documentation

```
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
  );
  await FirebaseAppCheck.instance
      .activate(
    androidProvider: AndroidProvider.playIntegrity,
    appleProvider: AppleProvider.appAttest,
    webProvider: ReCaptchaV3Provider('recaptcha-v3-site-key'),
  );
```

Everything was working, but in last two month most users don't receive sms,
**instead the app opens web browser and then returns back, no sms code, just nothing**.

It all happens in working production application. When i was trying to find out i decided that it was happening because of app check, because i have only this error logs, somehow i tried to fix app check, but with no result. For now i can't turn off or make app check work correctly. App check is not starting authentification process. I am totally stack, don't know how to fix, advice please.

```
I/IMM_LC  (30757): ssi() - flag : 0 view : com.asylzatwww.poputkakg reason = SHOW_SOFT_INPUT
I/IMM_LC  (30757): ssi() view is not EditText
I/IMM_LC  (30757): showSoftInput(View,I)
I/IMM_LC  (30757): ssi() - flag : 0 view : com.asylzatwww.poputkakg reason = SHOW_SOFT_INPUT
I/IMM_LC  (30757): ssi() view is not EditText
I/zzf     (30757): ForceRecaptchaFlow from phoneAuthOptions = false, ForceRecaptchaFlow from firebaseSettings = false
W/System  (30757): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
D/InputConnectionAdaptor(30757): The input method toggled cursor monitoring on
W/OnBackInvokedCallback(30757): OnBackInvokedCallback is not enabled for the application.
W/OnBackInvokedCallback(30757): Set 'android:enableOnBackInvokedCallback="true"' in the application manifest.
D/InputConnectionAdaptor(30757): The input method toggled text monitoring on
I/flutter (30757): HJKKKKKKK
I/flutter (30757): ghhhhhhhhhhh {type: 14, operation: success}
I/ViewRootImpl@e7f7105[MainActivity](30757): Resizing android.view.ViewRootImpl@5d83714: frame = [0,0][1080,2400] reportDraw = false forceLayout = false syncSeqId = 0
D/TrafficStats(30757): tagSocket(83) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
D/InsetsController(30757): onStateChanged: InsetsState: {mDisplayFrame=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 2400), mDisplayCutout=DisplayCutout{insets=Rect(0, 88 - 0, 0) waterfall=Insets{left=0, top=0, right=0, bottom=0} boundingRect={Bounds=[Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0), Rect(512, 0 - 568, 88), Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0), Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0)]} cutoutPathParserInfo={CutoutPathParserInfo{displayWidth=1080 displayHeight=2400 physicalDisplayWidth=1080 physicalDisplayHeight=2400 density={2.625} cutoutSpec={M 0,0 M 0,12.25101276465640 a 10.60613009248640,10.60613009248640 0 1,0 0,21.21226018497290 a 10.60613009248640,10.60613009248640 0 1,0 0,-21.21226018497290 Z @dp} rotation={0} scale={1.0} physicalPixelDisplaySizeRatio={1.0}}}}, mRoundedCorners=RoundedCorners{[RoundedCorner{position=TopLeft, radius=84, center=Point(84, 84)}, RoundedCorner{position=TopRight, radius=84, center=Point(996, 84)}, RoundedCorner{position=BottomRight, radius=84, center=Point(996, 2316)}, RoundedCorner{position=BottomLeft, radius=84, center=Point(84, 2316)}]}  mRoundedCornerFrame=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 2400), mPrivacyIndicatorBounds=PrivacyIndicatorBounds {static bounds=Rect(964, 0 - 1080, 88) rotation=0}, mSources= { InsetsSource: {mType=ITYPE_STATUS_BAR, mFrame=[0,0][1080,88], mVisible=true, mInsetsRoundedCornerFrame=false}, InsetsSource: {mType=ITYPE_NAVIGATION_BAR, mFrame=[0,2274][1080,2400], mVisible=true, mInsetsRoundedCornerFrame=false}, InsetsSource: {mType=ITYPE_LEFT_GESTURES, mFrame=[0,0][0,2400], mVisible=true, mInsetsRoundedCornerFrame=false}, InsetsSource: {mType=ITYPE_RIGHT_GESTURES, mFrame=[1080,0][1080,2400], mVisible=true, mInsetsRoundedCornerFrame=false}, InsetsSource: {mType=ITYPE_TOP_MANDATORY_GESTURES, mFrame=[0,0][1080,120], mVisible=true, mInsetsRoundedCornerFrame=false}, InsetsSource: {mType=ITYPE_BOTTOM_MANDATORY_GESTURES, mFrame=[0,2274][1080,2400], mVisible=true, mInsetsRoundedCornerFrame=false}, InsetsSource: {mType=ITYPE_LEFT_DISPLAY_CUTOUT, mFrame=[0,0][-100000,2400], mVisible=true, mInsetsRoundedCornerFrame=false}, InsetsSource: {mType=ITYPE_TOP_DISPLAY_CUTOUT, mFrame=[0,0][1080,88], mVisible=true, mInsetsRoundedCornerFrame=false}, InsetsSource: {mType=ITYPE_RIGHT_DISPLAY_CUTOUT, mFrame=[100000,0][1080,2400], mVisible=true, mInsetsRoundedCornerFrame=false}, InsetsSource: {mType=ITYPE_BOTTOM_DISPLAY_CUTOUT, mFrame=[0,100000][1080,2400], mVisible=true, mInsetsRoundedCornerFrame=false}, InsetsSource: {mType=ITYPE_TOP_TAPPABLE_ELEMENT, mFrame=[0,0][1080,88], mVisible=true, mInsetsRoundedCornerFrame=false}, InsetsSource: {mType=ITYPE_BOTTOM_TAPPABLE_ELEMENT, mFrame=[0,2274][1080,2400], mVisible=true, mInsetsRoundedCornerFrame=false}, InsetsSource: {mType=ITYPE_IME, mFrame=[0,1409][1080,2400], mVisibleFrame=[0,1409][1080,2400], mVisible=false, mInsetsRoundedCornerFrame=false} } host=com.asylzatwww.poputkakg/com.asylzatwww.poputkakg.MainActivity from=android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessageImpl:6727
I/ViewRootImpl@e7f7105[MainActivity](30757): handleResized, msg = 4 frames=ClientWindowFrames{frame=[0,0][1080,2400] display=[0,0][1080,2400] parentFrame=[0,0][0,0] parentClippedByDisplayCutout=false} forceNextWindowRelayout=false displayId=0 resizeMode=-1 frameChanged=false displayFrameChanged=false configChanged=false displayChanged=false
D/InsetsController(30757): show(ime(), fromIme=true)
D/InsetsController(30757): controlAnimationUnchecked: Added types=8 animType=0 host=com.asylzatwww.poputkakg/com.asylzatwww.poputkakg.MainActivity from=android.view.InsetsController.applyAnimation:1576 android.view.InsetsController.applyAnimation:1557 android.view.InsetsController.show:1063 
D/InsetsSourceConsumer(30757): setRequestedVisible: visible=true, type=19, host=com.asylzatwww.poputkakg/com.asylzatwww.poputkakg.MainActivity, from=android.view.InsetsSourceConsumer.show:250 android.view.ImeInsetsSourceConsumer.show:82 android.view.InsetsController.showDirectly:1609 android.view.InsetsController.controlAnimationUnchecked:1232 android.view.InsetsController.applyAnimation:1576 android.view.InsetsController.applyAnimation:1557 android.view.InsetsController.show:1063 android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessageImpl:6761 android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage:6697 android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage:106 
I/ViewRootImpl@e7f7105[MainActivity](30757): mWNT: t=0xb400007590c94900 mBlastBufferQueue=0xb400007631a4ca80 fn= 60 caller= android.view.SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier.applyTransaction:96 android.view.SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier.lambda$scheduleApply$0$android-view-SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier:69 android.view.SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onFrameDraw:4 
D/InsetsController(30757): show(ime(), fromIme=true)
I/ViewRootImpl@e7f7105[MainActivity](30757): mWNT: t=0xb400007590dbff00 mBlastBufferQueue=0xb400007631a4ca80 fn= 61 caller= android.view.SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier.applyTransaction:96 android.view.SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier.lambda$scheduleApply$0$android-view-SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier:69 android.view.SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onFrameDraw:4 
I/ViewRootImpl@e7f7105[MainActivity](30757): Resizing android.view.ViewRootImpl@5d83714: frame = [0,0][1080,2400] reportDraw = false forceLayout = false syncSeqId = 0
D/InsetsController(30757): onStateChanged: InsetsState: {mDisplayFrame=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 2400), mDisplayCutout=DisplayCutout{insets=Rect(0, 88 - 0, 0) waterfall=Insets{left=0, top=0, right=0, bottom=0} boundingRect={Bounds=[Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0), Rect(512, 0 - 568, 88), Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0), Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0)]} cutoutPathParserInfo={CutoutPathParserInfo{displayWidth=1080 displayHeight=2400 physicalDisplayWidth=1080 physicalDisplayHeight=2400 density={2.625} cutoutSpec={M 0,0 M 0,12.25101276465640 a 10.60613009248640,10.60613009248640 0 1,0 0,21.21226018497290 a 10.60613009248640,10.60613009248640 0 1,0 0,-21.21226018497290 Z @dp} rotation={0} scale={1.0} physicalPixelDisplaySizeRatio={1.0}}}}, mRoundedCorners=RoundedCorners{[RoundedCorner{position=TopLeft, radius=84, center=Point(84, 84)}, RoundedCorner{position=TopRight, radius=84, center=Point(996, 84)}, RoundedCorner{position=BottomRight, radius=84, center=Point(996, 2316)}, RoundedCorner{position=BottomLeft, radius=84, center=Point(84, 2316)}]}  mRoundedCornerFrame=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 2400), mPrivacyIndicatorBounds=PrivacyIndicatorBounds {static bounds=Rect(964, 0 - 1080, 88) rotation=0}, mSources= { InsetsSource: {mType=ITYPE_STATUS_BAR, mFrame=[0,0][1080,88], mVisible=true, mInsetsRoundedCornerFrame=false}, InsetsSource: {mType=ITYPE_NAVIGATION_BAR, mFrame=[0,2274][1080,2400], mVisible=true, mInsetsRoundedCornerFrame=false}, InsetsSource: {mType=ITYPE_LEFT_GESTURES, mFrame=[0,0][0,2400], mVisible=true, mInsetsRoundedCornerFrame=false}, InsetsSource: {mType=ITYPE_RIGHT_GESTURES, mFrame=[1080,0][1080,2400], mVisible=true, mInsetsRoundedCornerFrame=false}, InsetsSource: {mType=ITYPE_TOP_MANDATORY_GESTURES, mFrame=[0,0][1080,120], mVisible=true, mInsetsRoundedCornerFrame=false}, InsetsSource: {mType=ITYPE_BOTTOM_MANDATORY_GESTURES, mFrame=[0,2274][1080,2400], mVisible=true, mInsetsRoundedCornerFrame=false}, InsetsSource: {mType=ITYPE_LEFT_DISPLAY_CUTOUT, mFrame=[0,0][-100000,2400], mVisible=true, mInsetsRoundedCornerFrame=false}, InsetsSource: {mType=ITYPE_TOP_DISPLAY_CUTOUT, mFrame=[0,0][1080,88], mVisible=true, mInsetsRoundedCornerFrame=false}, InsetsSource: {mType=ITYPE_RIGHT_DISPLAY_CUTOUT, mFrame=[100000,0][1080,2400], mVisible=true, mInsetsRoundedCornerFrame=false}, InsetsSource: {mType=ITYPE_BOTTOM_DISPLAY_CUTOUT, mFrame=[0,100000][1080,2400], mVisible=true, mInsetsRoundedCornerFrame=false}, InsetsSource: {mType=ITYPE_TOP_TAPPABLE_ELEMENT, mFrame=[0,0][1080,88], mVisible=true, mInsetsRoundedCornerFrame=false}, InsetsSource: {mType=ITYPE_BOTTOM_TAPPABLE_ELEMENT, mFrame=[0,2274][1080,2400], mVisible=true, mInsetsRoundedCornerFrame=false}, InsetsSource: {mType=ITYPE_IME, mFrame=[0,1409][1080,2400], mVisibleFrame=[0,1409][1080,2400], mVisible=true, mInsetsRoundedCornerFrame=false} } host=com.asylzatwww.poputkakg/com.asylzatwww.poputkakg.MainActivity from=android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessageImpl:6740
I/ViewRootImpl@e7f7105[MainActivity](30757): handleResized, msg = 4 frames=ClientWindowFrames{frame=[0,0][1080,2400] display=[0,0][1080,2400] parentFrame=[0,0][0,0] parentClippedByDisplayCutout=false} forceNextWindowRelayout=false displayId=0 resizeMode=-1 frameChanged=false displayFrameChanged=false configChanged=false displayChanged=false
I/ViewRootImpl@e7f7105[MainActivity](30757): mWNT: t=0xb400007625e42f00 mBlastBufferQueue=0xb400007631a4ca80 fn= 62 caller= android.view.SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier.applyTransaction:96 android.view.SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier.lambda$scheduleApply$0$android-view-SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier:69 android.view.SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onFrameDraw:4 
I/ViewRootImpl@e7f7105[MainActivity](30757): mWNT: t=0xb4000076201c0100 mBlastBufferQueue=0xb400007631a4ca80 fn= 63 caller= android.view.SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier.applyTransaction:96 android.view.SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier.lambda$scheduleApply$0$android-view-SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier:69 android.view.SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onFrameDraw:4 
I/ViewRootImpl@e7f7105[MainActivity](30757): mWNT: t=0xb4000076201c0300 mBlastBufferQueue=0xb400007631a4ca80 fn= 64 caller= android.view.SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier.applyTransaction:96 android.view.SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier.lambda$scheduleApply$0$android-view-SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier:69 android.view.SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onFrameDraw:4 
I/ViewRootImpl@e7f7105[MainActivity](30757): mWNT: t=0xb4000076201c0500 mBlastBufferQueue=0xb400007631a4ca80 fn= 65 caller= android.view.SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier.applyTransaction:96 android.view.SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier.lambda$scheduleApply$0$android-view-SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier:69 android.view.SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onFrameDraw:4 
I/ViewRootImpl@e7f7105[MainActivity](30757): mWNT: t=0xb4000076201c0700 mBlastBufferQueue=0xb400007631a4ca80 fn= 66 caller= android.view.SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier.applyTransaction:96 android.view.SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier.lambda$scheduleApply$0$android-view-SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier:69 android.view.SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onFrameDraw:4 
I/ViewRootImpl@e7f7105[MainActivity](30757): mWNT: t=0xb4000076201c0900 mBlastBufferQueue=0xb400007631a4ca80 fn= 67 caller= android.view.SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier.applyTransaction:96 android.view.SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier.lambda$scheduleApply$0$android-view-SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier:69 android.view.SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onFrameDraw:4 
I/flutter (30757): HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH1
I/flutter (30757): HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH2
I/flutter (30757): false
I/ViewRootImpl@e7f7105[MainActivity](30757): mWNT: t=0xb4000076201c0b00 mBlastBufferQueue=0xb400007631a4ca80 fn= 68 caller= android.view.SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier.applyTransaction:96 android.view.SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier.lambda$scheduleApply$0$android-view-SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier:69 android.view.SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onFrameDraw:4 
I/ViewRootImpl@e7f7105[MainActivity](30757): mWNT: t=0xb4000076201c0d00 mBlastBufferQueue=0xb400007631a4ca80 fn= 69 caller= android.view.SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier.applyTransaction:96 android.view.SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier.lambda$scheduleApply$0$android-view-SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier:69 android.view.SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onFrameDraw:4 
I/ViewRootImpl@e7f7105[MainActivity](30757): mWNT: t=0xb4000076201c0f00 mBlastBufferQueue=0xb400007631a4ca80 fn= 70 caller= android.view.SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier.applyTransaction:96 android.view.SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier.lambda$scheduleApply$0$android-view-SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier:69 android.view.SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onFrameDraw:4 
I/ViewRootImpl@e7f7105[MainActivity](30757): mWNT: t=0xb400007622303100 mBlastBufferQueue=0xb400007631a4ca80 fn= 71 caller= android.view.SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier.applyTransaction:96 android.view.SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier.lambda$scheduleApply$0$android-view-SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier:69 android.view.SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onFrameDraw:4 
I/ViewRootImpl@e7f7105[MainActivity](30757): mWNT: t=0xb400007622303800 mBlastBufferQueue=0xb400007631a4ca80 fn= 72 caller= android.view.SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier.applyTransaction:96 android.view.SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier.lambda$scheduleApply$0$android-view-SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier:69 android.view.SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onFrameDraw:4 
I/ViewRootImpl@e7f7105[MainActivity](30757): mWNT: t=0xb4000075b4259e00 mBlastBufferQueue=0xb400007631a4ca80 fn= 73 caller= android.view.SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier.applyTransaction:96 android.view.SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier.lambda$scheduleApply$0$android-view-SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier:69 android.view.SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onFrameDraw:4 
I/flutter (30757): HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH1
I/flutter (30757): HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH2
I/flutter (30757): false
I/ViewRootImpl@e7f7105[MainActivity](30757): mWNT: t=0xb4000075b4273800 mBlastBufferQueue=0xb400007631a4ca80 fn= 74 caller= android.view.SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier.applyTransaction:96 android.view.SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier.lambda$scheduleApply$0$android-view-SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier:69 android.view.SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onFrameDraw:4 
I/ViewRootImpl@e7f7105[MainActivity](30757): mWNT: t=0xb4000076201c0200 mBlastBufferQueue=0xb400007631a4ca80 fn= 75 caller= android.view.SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier.applyTransaction:96 android.view.SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier.lambda$scheduleApply$0$android-view-SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier:69 android.view.SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onFrameDraw:4 
I/ViewRootImpl@e7f7105[MainActivity](30757): mWNT: t=0xb400007620272100 mBlastBufferQueue=0xb400007631a4ca80 fn= 76 caller= android.view.SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier.applyTransaction:96 android.view.SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier.lambda$scheduleApply$0$android-view-SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier:69 android.view.SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onFrameDraw:4 
I/ViewRootImpl@e7f7105[MainActivity](30757): mWNT: t=0xb400007590c94100 mBlastBufferQueue=0xb400007631a4ca80 fn= 77 caller= android.view.SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier.applyTransaction:96 android.view.SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier.lambda$scheduleApply$0$android-view-SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier:69 android.view.SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onFrameDraw:4 
I/flutter (30757): HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH1
I/flutter (30757): HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH2
I/flutter (30757): false
I/ViewRootImpl@e7f7105[MainActivity](30757): mWNT: t=0xb400007625ca7900 mBlastBufferQueue=0xb400007631a4ca80 fn= 78 caller= android.view.SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier.applyTransaction:96 android.view.SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier.lambda$scheduleApply$0$android-view-SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier:69 android.view.SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onFrameDraw:4 
I/ViewRootImpl@e7f7105[MainActivity](30757): mWNT: t=0xb4000076201c0100 mBlastBufferQueue=0xb400007631a4ca80 fn= 79 caller= android.view.SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier.applyTransaction:96 android.view.SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier.lambda$scheduleApply$0$android-view-SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier:69 android.view.SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onFrameDraw:4 
I/ViewRootImpl@e7f7105[MainActivity](30757): mWNT: t=0xb4000076201c0500 mBlastBufferQueue=0xb400007631a4ca80 fn= 80 caller= android.view.SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier.applyTransaction:96 android.view.SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier.lambda$scheduleApply$0$android-view-SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier:69 android.view.SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onFrameDraw:4 
I/ViewRootImpl@e7f7105[MainActivity](30757): mWNT: t=0xb400007622322300 mBlastBufferQueue=0xb400007631a4ca80 fn= 81 caller= android.view.SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier.applyTransaction:96 android.view.SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier.lambda$scheduleApply$0$android-view-SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier:69 android.view.SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onFrameDraw:4 
I/ViewRootImpl@e7f7105[MainActivity](30757): mWNT: t=0xb400007590dbff00 mBlastBufferQueue=0xb400007631a4ca80 fn= 82 caller= android.view.SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier.applyTransaction:96 android.view.SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier.lambda$scheduleApply$0$android-view-SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier:69 android.view.SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onFrameDraw:4 
I/ViewRootImpl@e7f7105[MainActivity](30757): mWNT: t=0xb4000076201c0a00 mBlastBufferQueue=0xb400007631a4ca80 fn= 83 caller= android.view.SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier.applyTransaction:96 android.view.SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier.lambda$scheduleApply$0$android-view-SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier:69 android.view.SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onFrameDraw:4 
I/flutter (30757): HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH1
I/flutter (30757): HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH2
I/flutter (30757): false
I/ViewRootImpl@e7f7105[MainActivity](30757): mWNT: t=0xb400007622303700 mBlastBufferQueue=0xb400007631a4ca80 fn= 84 caller= android.view.SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier.applyTransaction:96 android.view.SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier.lambda$scheduleApply$0$android-view-SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier:69 android.view.SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onFrameDraw:4 
I/ViewRootImpl@e7f7105[MainActivity](30757): mWNT: t=0xb4000076201c0300 mBlastBufferQueue=0xb400007631a4ca80 fn= 85 caller= android.view.SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier.applyTransaction:96 android.view.SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier.lambda$scheduleApply$0$android-view-SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier:69 android.view.SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onFrameDraw:4 
I/ViewRootImpl@e7f7105[MainActivity](30757): mWNT: t=0xb4000076201c0800 mBlastBufferQueue=0xb400007631a4ca80 fn= 86 caller= android.view.SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier.applyTransaction:96 android.view.SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier.lambda$scheduleApply$0$android-view-SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier:69 android.view.SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onFrameDraw:4 
D/InsetsController(30757): cancelAnimation of types: 8, animType: 0, host: com.asylzatwww.poputkakg/com.asylzatwww.poputkakg.MainActivity, from:android.view.InsetsController.notifyFinished:1375 android.view.InsetsAnimationControlImpl.applyChangeInsets:285 android.view.InsetsController.lambda$new$3$android-view-InsetsController:674 
D/InsetsSourceConsumer(30757): ensureControlPosition: Point(0, 88) for ITYPE_IME on com.asylzatwww.poputkakg/com.asylzatwww.poputkakg.MainActivity from android.view.InsetsSourceConsumer.notifyAnimationFinished:419
I/ViewRootImpl@e7f7105[MainActivity](30757): mWNT: t=0xb4000076201c0900 mBlastBufferQueue=0xb400007631a4ca80 fn= 87 caller= android.view.SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier.applyTransaction:96 android.view.SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier.lambda$scheduleApply$0$android-view-SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier:69 android.view.SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onFrameDraw:4 
I/ViewRootImpl@e7f7105[MainActivity](30757): mWNT: t=0xb4000076201c0d00 mBlastBufferQueue=0xb400007631a4ca80 fn= 87 caller= android.view.SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier.applyTransaction:96 android.view.SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier.lambda$scheduleApply$0$android-view-SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier:69 android.view.SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onFrameDraw:4 
I/flutter (30757): HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH1
I/flutter (30757): HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH2
I/flutter (30757): false
W/LocalRequestInterceptor(30757): Error getting App Check token; using placeholder token instead. Error: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: Error returned from API. code: 403 body: App attestation failed.
D/TrafficStats(30757): tagSocket(149) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
I/PlayCore(30757): UID: [10322]  PID: [30757] IntegrityService : requestIntegrityToken(IntegrityTokenRequest{nonce=Ive4zYnH1L1zhEtwncO8SHuYuCFJ6VP8o1J_aSxGvxs, cloudProjectNumber=551503664846})
I/PlayCore(30757): UID: [10322]  PID: [30757] IntegrityService : Initiate binding to the service.
I/PlayCore(30757): UID: [10322]  PID: [30757] IntegrityService : ServiceConnectionImpl.onServiceConnected(ComponentInfo{com.android.vending/com.google.android.finsky.integrityservice.IntegrityService})
I/PlayCore(30757): UID: [10322]  PID: [30757] IntegrityService : linkToDeath
I/PlayCore(30757): UID: [10322]  PID: [30757] OnRequestIntegrityTokenCallback : onRequestIntegrityToken
I/PlayCore(30757): UID: [10322]  PID: [30757] IntegrityService : Unbind from service.
W/OnBackInvokedCallback(30757): OnBackInvokedCallback is not enabled for the application.
W/OnBackInvokedCallback(30757): Set 'android:enableOnBackInvokedCallback="true"' in the application manifest.
W/System  (30757): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
W/LocalRequestInterceptor(30757): Error getting App Check token; using placeholder token instead. Error: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: Too many attempts.
E/FirebaseAuth(30757): [SmsRetrieverHelper] SMS verification code request failed: unknown status code: 17499 Firebase App Check token is invalid.
D/FirebaseAuth(30757): Invoking original failure callbacks after phone verification failure for +996700755858, error - An internal error has occurred. [ Firebase App Check token is invalid. ]
I/flutter (30757): Verification failed: An internal error has occurred. [ Firebase App Check token is invalid. ]
I/flutter (30757): One second has passed!
```

Comment: did you check the SHA keys ? Might be that your appCheckToken does not know the Google Play console SHA keys. You are being rejected.

Comment: @Athlas yes i checked the sha keys, everything set correctly, reading all documentations, but still not working, the authentifications throught sms not working.

Answer (score 3):

I see that you have

```
 await FirebaseAppCheck.instance
      .activate(
    androidProvider: AndroidProvider.playIntegrity,
    appleProvider: AppleProvider.appAttest,
    webProvider: ReCaptchaV3Provider('recaptcha-v3-site-key'),
  );
```

whereas you should have

```
if(!kDebugMode) {
        await FirebaseAppCheck.instance.activate(
          androidProvider: AndroidProvider.playIntegrity,
          appleProvider: AppleProvider.appAttest,
          webProvider: ReCaptchaV3Provider('recaptcha-v3-site-key'),
        );
      } else {
        await FirebaseAppCheck.instance.activate(
          androidProvider: AndroidProvider.debug,
          appleProvider: AppleProvider.debug,
        );
      }
```

If you are in DebugMode, you should use AndroidProvider.debug and AppleProvider.debug. For release you can use the API you want.

When you use AndroidProvider.debug or AppleProvider.debug, it will pop a message in console logs.

An example :

> D/com.google.firebase.appcheck.debug.internal.DebugAppCheckProvider(
> 8496): Enter this debug secret into the allow list in the Firebase
> Console for your project: fc2ada97-ef39-4273-857c-b767c241114c

Enter it in your firebase App Check menu, then Application tab, then manage debug token !

It should work now, let me know if that does not work after this steps.

Comment: I did as you said, and added log files to the answer, it is for debug mode. But there wasn't DebugAppCheckProvider inside logs. Also the strange thing is, the project number of firebase is 455523360544 , in debug i saw the line IntegrityService : requestIntegrityToken(IntegrityTokenRequest{nonce=SAsbNMArCZuG8rTEo6iRMjwbCutuFxFkKCMt0NCLHek, cloudProjectNumber=551503664846}) the cloudProjectNumber is differs, is it relevant to error?

Comment: Indeed, the project number in your firebase global parameters should match your google cloud project number.